# Radio Button circular in chrome, but square in firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So as stated in the title, everything is the same in CSS and HTML but for some reason firefox displays the radio buttons as square.

If you open http://jsfiddle.net/u2yq3j50/4/ in Chrome the radio buttons appear as circles. If you open it in Firefox it appears as squares.

I've tried    `-moz-appearance: radio;`  in `#radio-demo input[type="radio"] + label:before` but that does not give the desired output because it just overrides my stylings and makes it not selectable.

Any tips would be great, thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing the un-prefixed `border-radius` and `box-shadow` properties. In fact, you don't need any prefixes for those properties any more. Same for `opacity`.

Comment: thanks! I think it was the un-prefixed border-radius! For the background can I just use un-prefixed version too? Also could you explain why this happens when I only used prefixed versions of border-radius or is this just a weird quirk for css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics come first:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Check this on out:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/u2yq3j50/14/)

I sometimes am so tied up with browser compatibility that I forget all about the un-prefixed versions. [Here's an "ok" website](http://css3generator.com/) where it generates the basic css3 code and then you can add the prefixes for other browsers

Comment: I'd just like to point out that 95% of vendor prefixes aren't needed any more. The biggest exceptions are `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-animation`, which for some reason are still not supported "naturally" in Chrome.

Comment: @nietthedarkabsol Well, thanks for pointing that out, for now I still feel safer if I use them ^^. Like you said, some are still not supported and I would not like it if by mistake I forgot to place those exceptions, so I rather place them all, no harm in that :)